# No routes matched location "/" I'm getting this error every time i try to wrap my app

Tags: function, browser, routes

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <main className="container">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/Rentals" component={Rentals} />
        </Routes>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

the code is not working i get no routes matched location

Answer (score 0):

The "No routes matched location '/'" error means that it cannot find the index path. Routes need to start at location "/" aka the index. Try something like this:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <main className="container">
        <Routes>
          <Route index component={<default website here>} />
          <Route path="/Rentals" component={Rentals} />
        </Routes>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Alternatively, if you still want to start at the '/Rentals' page, you can do:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <main className="container">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/Rentals"/>} />
          <Route path="/Rentals" component={Rentals} />
        </Routes>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```